# Failed vhd copy: "the blob type is invalid for this operation"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to clone a virtual machine on Azure. I stopped the VM, and navigated to its VHD file in blob storage using Neudesic's Azure Storage Expolrer. But when I try to copy the BHD blob I get the error "the blob type is invalid for this operation" after the target blob is created but before any bytes are copied. What steps am I missing?

Comment: Just noticed the 'close' vote; that makes sense, perhaps I should have posted this on the SuperUser SE instead. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have found a bug in Azure Storage Explorer. It is basically trying to copy as `Block Blob` where your original blob type is `Page Blob`.

What I did was I tried to copy a VHD file and captured the request in Fiddler. If you see the screenshot below, you'll notice that the `x-ms-blob-type` request header is going as `BlockBlob` instead of `PageBlob`.

[image]

Comment: That didn't work. Well it might have but to copy the VHD from one container to another on the same storage account Azure Explorer wanted to copy the bytes via my local machine which would have taken hours and hours and hours. I need the copy to happen purely on Azure to minimize downtime for the virtual machine. ==EDIT== No, it looks like the blob copy was immediate! Not sure what the copy indicator was doing.

Comment: So, was the VHD copied properly without being downloaded and reuploaded?

Comment: I could not use the VHD that Azure Explorer copied to create a disk, so I tried your method again but using CloudXplorer. That seemed to do the copy quickly without sticking at 0% and showing me a Kbits/s figure. The resulting copied VHD worked as the basis for a new dist.

Comment: You're correct. I was under the impression that Azure Explorer supported async blob copy but it turns out, it didn't. Sorry about that. I should have checked before recommending. I've updated my answer. But I'm glad that you were able to copy VHDs.